# Jenkins copy code after commit to local machine

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have code repository in github. After committing the code, jenkins build starts. After successful build, code needs to be copied to local machine. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Where is jenkins build run? Is it on your local machine? Do you want to copy the code on the same machine after successful build?

Answer (score 0):

Your question looks very fuzzy, as you have not clearly mentioned :

1. where is your jenkins running.
2. Are there multiple people contributing to the same code base and the jenkins should be able to copy code to everyone's local after anyone's commit build is finished.
3. What will happen in case of an unsuccessful build?

I am proceeding here with my assumptions :

1. Jenkins is running in a master salve configuration in a remote machine
2. for now I assume we only need to copy code on one remote machine
3. There will be no copy in case of commit build failure.

To achieve this :

- Jenkins part -

  1. Script : which you will trigger in the jenkins to build the package whenever code is committed. If there is a failure of package
     building, don't do anything(or trigger a mail/alert), in case of
     success ssh to the remote server and copy the code there.
- Git integration with jenkins : You can refer to this [link](https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/better-integration-between-jenkins-and-github-github-jenkins-plugin), as it
  is very detailed there is no need to mention anything here.

If you had any other requirement, pls comment.